# SIM800l keeps disconnecting after I send at+sapbr =1,1

Tags: arduino, at-commands, gprs

I have confirmed my SIM card has data and can connect to the internet on my smartphone. The SIM800l also is fed with enough power and the LED does blink every three seconds.

I set up my SIM800l module with the basic AT commands:

```
AT

AT+CFUN=1
```

I then enter the APN settings for my SIM card as follows:

```
AT+SAPBR=3,1,"CONTYPE","GPRS"

OK
AT+SAPBR=3,1,"APN","Internet"

OK
```

Now as soon as I enter this code:

```
AT+SAPBR=1,1

OK
```

my SIM800l KED starts blinking every second. When I started the module it blinked every 3 second (connection was made).

When I then enter this command:

```
AT+SAPBR=0,1
```

my SIM800l LED then goes back to blinking every three seconds. This is very strange. Can someone assist me with this error?

My application is to post a URL link.

Comment: According to the AT-command manual,  the AT+SAPBR=0,1 command closes the bearer connection. From what you are describing the module does at it is supposed to.

Comment: @PeterKarlsen even this **AT+SAPBR=1,1**  responds with OK, but the module physically shows it is now disconnected as per the LED blinking every second as compared to every three seconds. In addition after posting the data, I get this response **+HTTPACTION: 1,603,0**

Comment: Try sending AT+SAPBR=2,1 a few times after telling the module to open the bearer connection. It will show the status of the process. Are you sure the module is connected to the cellular network before attempting to open a bearer connection?

Comment: @PeterKarlsen the module is assigned an IP address. My concern is, everything in the software is showing that the module is working as expected. But the LED on the device shows the opposite since it loses it connection by blinking every second rather than every three seconds. When using at+sapbr=1,1, is the module suppose to blink its LED every second?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, this is a power issue. The module isn't getting enough power it requires when you open bearer. Try putting a 2200uf capacitor between the vcc and gnd of the module.